# How to take variable and use at other method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
string.Join(", ", CampaignManagementService.GetAdvertisers((string) Session["ticket"]).Select(kv => kv.Key.ToString()).ToArray())
```

From this method I get ID's but I don't know how to use those in another method for example:

```
String.Join(", ", CampaignManagementService.GetCampaigns((string)Session["ticket"] , (int) 16156).Select(x => x.Key + " - " + x.Value));
```

In this method I need ID | `(int) 16156` | but this is only static ID value I want to put ID from first method

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're asking. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: For example from first method I get ID's like 2554,1356,3466 and I want to use those in second method replace this (int) 16156 to MyIdsFromFirstMethod

Comment: So maybe u can help me to get ID ? I'm newbie at developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume several things using my psychic debugging powers:

1. `CampaignManagementService.GetAdvertisers` takes a `string` and returns a `Dictionary<int, Advertiser>`
2. The key of the dictionary is the ID of the advertiser returned.
3. You do the string.Join(...) on that so you'll get a comma separated list that is easy to transfer to the client and display there
4. You need to somehow get all campaigns for all advertisers you've gotten from the dictionary.
5. The campaigns for each advertiser are stored in a `Dictionary<int, string>` where the key is the ID of the campaign and the value is, lets say, the name of the campaign

Under those assumptions:

```
var ticket = (string) Session["ticket"];
var advertisers = CampaignManagementService.GetAdvertisers(ticket);
```

will give you the advertisers dictionary

```
var advertiserIDs = advertisers.Select(kv => kv.Key)
var strAdvertiserIDs = advertisers.Select(kv => kv.Key.ToString())
```

and will give you, respectively, an `IEnumerable<int>` and a `IEnumerable<string>` that will contain the advertiser IDs

```
var csvAdvertisers = string.Join(", ", strAdvertiserIDs)
```

will give you the original comma-separated list of IDs (no `.ToArray()` is necessary, since `string.Join` has an overload that accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`).
Next, to get all the campaings you can use the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method, like this:

```
var campaignsKvp = advertiserIDs.SelectMany(id =>
                             CampaignManagementService.GetCampaigns(ticket, id))
```

That will give you an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` which is not a really good data structure, but you can transform it using:

```
var campaigns = campaignsKvp.Select(kvp => kvp.Key.ToString() + "-"+kvp.Value);
var csvCampaigns = string.Join(", ", campaigns)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that:

```
CampaignManagementService.GetAdvertisers((string) Session["ticket"])
                         .SelectMany(kv => CampaignManagementService.GetCampaigns((string)Session["ticket"] , kv.Key))
                         .Select(x => x.Key + " - " + x.Value)
```

Comment: But i need get it like variable(somhow all ID like variables), and use it for another methods

Comment: You can split it this way: "var ids = CampaignManagementService.GetAdvertisers((string) Session["ticket"]).Select(kv => kv.Key)" and later "ids.SelectMany(id => CampaignManagementService.GetCampaigns((string)Session["ticket"] , id)).Select(x => x.Key + " - " + x.Value)"

Answer (score 1):

You should transform the output into a readable format when you're about to display it to the user. I would suggest to avoid transforming your data until you need to.

```
public List<Advertiser> GetAdvertisers()
{
    return CampaignManagementService.GetAdvertisers((string) Session["ticket"]).ToList();
}

public List<Campaign> GetCampaigns(IEnumerable<Advertiser> advertisers)
{
    return advertisers.Select(a => CampaignManagementService.GetCampaigns((string)Session["ticket"],
                                   Convert.ToInt32(a.Key))).ToList();
}
```